# ASP.NET MVC 4 does not serialize multipart/form-data to C# object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I have weird problem. I have multiple forms with basic CRUD operations. The following is the one with the problem, but they all look basically like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Groups", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(vm => vm.Groep.Id)
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 150px;">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Groep.Naam) @Html.Partial("RequiredFieldIndicator")</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Groep.Naam)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Groep.PLCode) @Html.Partial("RequiredFieldIndicator")</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Groep.PLCode)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<div class="actionbuttons">
    @if (Model.FormEditModus == FormEditModus.Edit)
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Groups", new { id = @Model.Groep.Id })'">Terug</button>
    }
    @if (Model.FormEditModus == FormEditModus.Add)
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Groups")'">Terug</button>
    }
    <button id="saveGroupButton" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Opslaan</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Groups")'">Annuleren</button>
</div>
}
```

The viewmodel that I use looks like this:

```
using Models;

namespace Admin.Models
{
public class GroupEditViewModel
{
    public Groep Groep { get; set; }

    //enum
    public FormEditModus FormEditModus { get; set; }
}


public class Groep : ModelKeyEntity
{
    [StringLength(200), Required]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20), Required]
    public string PLCode { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ModelKeyEntity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
}
```

All pretty basic. That's why I am surprised when the action on the MVC always recieves a null object when the form is posted. To add insult to injury, all my other forms (which have the same setup and almost the same viewmodel) are working flawlessly. But this is the result after a post to the controller:

[image: Groep is null]

This is the POST information leading up to the error:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryUPb7u53aJYurdens
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Groep.Id"

20
------WebKitFormBoundaryUPb7u53aJYurdens
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Groep"

Models.Groep
------WebKitFormBoundaryUPb7u53aJYurdens
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Groep.Naam"

Polantx
------WebKitFormBoundaryUPb7u53aJYurdens
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Groep.PLCode"

PL2000x
------WebKitFormBoundaryUPb7u53aJYurdens--
```

Everything is (I think) what is should be. The only thing is MVC refuses to serialize the form data to an object.

Needless to say, I am pretty clueless at this point. Somebody else has a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default model binder doesn't handle nested complex objects well. I got around this by writing a simple jQuery extension to serialize form data and then using Json.Net in a custom model binder.

This feels really hacky, but it works great.

Here's the jQuery:

```
   $.fn.serializeToJson = function () {
    var $form = $(this[0]);
    var items = $form.serializeArray();
    var returnObj = {};
    var nestedObjectNames = [];

    $.each(items, function (i, item) {
        //Split nested objects and assign properties
        //You may want to make this recursive - currently only works one step deep, but that's all I need
        if (item.name.contains('.')) {
            var nameArray = item.name.split('.');
            if (nestedObjectNames.indexOf(nameArray[0]) < 0) {
                nestedObjectNames.push(nameArray[0]);
            }
            var tempObj = returnObj[nestedObjectNames[nestedObjectNames.indexOf(nameArray[0])]] || {};
            if (!tempObj[nameArray[1]]) {
                tempObj[nameArray[1]] = item.value;
            }
            returnObj[nestedObjectNames[nestedObjectNames.indexOf(nameArray[0])]] = tempObj;
        } else if (!returnObj[item.name]) {
            returnObj[item.name] = item.value;
        }
    });

    return returnObj;
};
```

Call it:

```
var data = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeToJson());
$.post(url, data).done(...
```

And then the binder:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Namespace.Web.Core.Binders
{
    public class JsonBinder<T> : IModelBinder
    {
       public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var jsonString = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params[0];
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

And in use:

```
public ActionResult WhateverAction([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonBinder<CustomViewModel>))]CustomViewModel viewModel)
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, you may need to stringify the data. Updated above.

Comment: I'll try this solution, but it feels to hacky for comfort.

Comment: I agree, but you'll need a custom model binder regardless of how you handle it.

An alternative would be reading your query string in the custom model binder and binding for that specific model. This was my generic approach to the problem since I have a lot of view models.

Answer (score 1):

I got the thing working! The Viewmodel mentioned in the starting post boils down to this ModelBinder:

```
public class GroepModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string id = request.Form.Get("Groep.Id");
        string naam = request.Form.Get("Groep.Naam");
        string plcode = request.Form.Get("Groep.PLCode");

        return new GroupEditViewModel
        {
            Groep = new Business.Models.Groep
            {
                Id = int.Parse(id),
                Naam = naam,
                PLCode = plcode
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Then just add it to the controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([ModelBinder(typeof(GroepModelBinder))]GroupEditViewModel groep)
```

And then the thing worked.